# How to neglect objects during stream grouping or partitioning?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

It is possible to neglect some elements during `Collectors.groupingBy` or `Collectors.partitioningBy`?

Of course I know I can place a `.filter()` anywhere in a stream. But my problem is that I have to run a rather complex and expensive evaluation, to decide in which "group" my objects should be divided into.

Moreover, there are always many objects that I would want to neglect during collecting.

Example: imagine a `List<Foo>`, that I want to split into 2 lists. That's easy, but how can I additionally neglect all objects that don't fit into my evaluated condition?

```
var map = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    foo -> {
        int bar = complexEvaluation(foo);
        if (bar > 1000) return true;
        if (bar < 0) return false;
        //TODO how to neglect the rest between 0-1000
    },
    Collectors.mapping(foo -> foo.id, Collectors.toSet())
));
```

Comment: If you don't want to use `filter()`, you may have to loop through those values and apply another set of `if` statements.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can't filter with `filter()` because you need the logic of said filter while grouping. Is that correct?

Comment: @JettoMartínez yet that's correct, because if I would want to apply a `filter()` before, I'd have to run the `complexEvaluation` twice. Once for the filter to neglect everything from 0-1000, and once for the grouping/parititioning. And the operation is too expensive to be running twice (contains database calls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `enum` to define your 3 cases:

```
enum Categories {
    HIGH, LOW, NEGATIVE
}

var map = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    foo -> {
        int bar = complexEvaluation(foo);
        if (bar > 1000) return HIGH;
        if (bar < 0) return NEGATIVE;
        return LOW;
    },
    Collectors.mapping(foo -> foo.id, Collectors.toSet())
));
```

Then ignore or remove `LOW` if you don’t need it. It also has the added benefits of giving more meaning to your categories instead of just naming them `true`/`false`, and making it easier to refactor if you need more categories in the future.

Only drawback is that it builds a useless `LOW` set, but that’s only an issue if it is really big compared to the other sets and the `complexEvaluation()` operation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid temporary storage, you have to implement your own collector:

```java
var map = foos.parallelStream().collect(
    () -> Map.of(true, new HashSet<ID>(), false, new HashSet<ID>()),
    (o, foo) -> {
        int bar = complexEvaluation(foo);
        ID id = foo.id;
        if (bar > 1000) o.get(true).add(id);
        else if (bar < 0) o.get(false).add(id);
    },
    (a, b) -> { a.get(true).addAll(b.get(true)); a.get(false).addAll(b.get(false)); }
);
```

This example has the same behavior as `partitioningBy`, always creating entries for `true` and `false`.

`ID` is a placeholder for the type of `foo.id` which you didn’t include in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To reuse the result of complexEvaluation in both `filter` and `groupingBy`, you can call before filtering and store the result in a wrapper class.

```
foos.stream()
    .map(foo -> {
        int bar = complexEvaluation(foo);
        if (bar > 1000) Pair.of(foo, true);
        if (bar < 0) Pair.of(foo, false);
        return Pair.of(foo, null);
    )
    .filter(fooPair -> fooPair.getRight() != null)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Pair::getRight(),
        Collectors.mapping(fooPair -> fooPair.getLeft().id, Collectors.toSet()
    );
```

However, this is only if you insist on using `groupingBy` for some reason.

An alternative with foreach would be much easier to read:

```
Map<Boolean, Set<Foo>> groups = new HashMap<>();
foos.stream()
    .forEach(foo -> {
        int bar = complexEvaluation(foo);
        if (bar > 1000) groups.computeIfAbsent(true, k->new HashSet<>()).add(foo);
        if (bar < 0)    groups.computeIfAbsent(false, k->new HashSet<>()).add(foo);
   })
```

Comment: Could you give an optimized example using `forEach`?

Comment: Added example with `forEach`

Comment: Yes, I see. That's what I started with, but thought it not that good to collect values from inside the stream into sets outside of the stream. But probably better suited for my case.

Comment: But then, you can also use `forEach(foo -> …)` instead of `.stream() .forEach(foo -> …)` or just use an ordinary `for(var foo: foos) …` and don’t have to worry about accessing artifacts outside the stream from within the stream.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intent correctly you want to filter out some values while collecting them. It's doable with [**`Collectors.filtering()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector)).

Note, that `filtering()` can eliminate all values for some buckets, but it'll not cause empty buckets to be removed. In the example below buckets for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 will be empty.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var foos = List.of(-100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1001, 1002, 1003);
        
        var map = foos.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                            UnaryOperator.identity(),
                            Collectors.filtering(foo -> foo < 0 || foo > 1000,
                                    Collectors.toSet())));

        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

**map**

```
{1=[], 2=[], 3=[], -100=[-100], 4=[], 5=[], 1001=[1001], 1002=[1002], 1003=[1003]}
```

**UPDATE**

I revised this problem and the solution provided below computes the values beforehand.

In this version, undesired entries are filtered out in the stream, which makes the code inside Collector easier to read. I hope that instead of `foo` objects integer is used isn't a problem.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> foos = List.of(-100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 101, 102, 103);

        Map<Integer, Integer> fooToValue = getFooToValueMap(foos);

        Map<Boolean, Set<Integer>> map = getFoosMap(fooToValue);

        System.out.println(map);
    }
```

```
    private static Map<Boolean, Set<Integer>> getFoosMap(Map<Integer, Integer> fooToValue) {
        return fooToValue.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() < 0 || entry.getValue() > 1000)
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                            entry -> entry.getValue() > 1000,
                            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toSet())
                ));
    }
```

```
    private static Map<Integer, Integer> getFooToValueMap(List<Integer> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(UnaryOperator.identity(), foo -> complexEvaluation(foo)));
    }
```

```
    private static int complexEvaluation(int foo) {
        return (int) Math.signum(foo) * foo * foo;
    }
```

**map**

```
{false=[-100], true=[101, 102, 103]}
```

Comment: That would be an option **if** one could extract `foo.id` before collecting it to the final set.

Comment: This only works if the value to filter on is readily available on the objects (without computation), in which case you are better of using `filter()` directly in the pipeline.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem: the values has to be computated...

Comment: @membersound then maybe it's possible to compute these values beforehand? Associate each value with the corresponding `foo ` object and then create a stream of map entries.

Comment: @membersound I've updated my comment so that the issue you've pointed out is addressed.